# Best practice to trigger interval sequence

Tags: jquery, animation

Is there a better way to carry out a sequence of animations than using setTimeout intervals to trigger the next item in the sequence?

```
   setTimeout(function() { 
       // Do something 
    }, 300);

    setTimeout(function() { 
       // Do something 
    }, 600);

    setTimeout(function() { 
       // Do something 
    }, 900);
```

Comment: You could use `$('#yourelement').delay(300).animate()`? Not entirely sure though

Comment: Are the animations supposed to follow up each other? most jquery animations have the possibility to provide a callback for when an animation finishes.

Comment: Hi @Me.Name. I am using CSS3 animations, so am just adding either classes or .css().

Comment: If you are using CSS, why not add the delay in the animation itself?